# How can i change the theme of a share intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

To keep my question as simple as possible, can i customise the colours used by the `Intent.ACTION_SEND` and if so how would i go about doing it?

Such as the text colour, background colour etc.

Comment: I'd like to know this too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the only customization that Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER supports is:

> You can specify the title that will appear in the activity chooser.

according to the docs (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CHOOSER)

**EDIT**
As an alternative, you could build your own dialog populating it with the list of activities that can respond to your send intent:

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
List activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
    PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
```

and handle the user selection by starting the chosen activity.

Comment: Ah, i could give that a try, Thanks for the help.